Unable To Locate Specific Values For Main Contract (or Project)
In the image below, I have specified certain users in these different "roles", specifically looking at the Notary. These are actual people and actual users in our instance.

When I make a call to the main-contracts/:id endpoint, the returned values are null for most of these entries.

Based on the documentation in APS, I should be seeing these entries. I am using a 3-legged token that includes scopes: data:read data:write account:read.
I realize that some of these values are populated directly from the Main Contract flyout, but, not all.
Any guidance is appreciated.

thanks for the report, unfortunately, it's a limitation of notaryCompanyId, the value is not returned correctly. ACSC-13877 was logged to track this improvement already.
